# Laplace Kernel in Matlab Libsvm

Tags: matlab, kernel, libsvm

Does anyone knows how I will study the laplace kernel on matlab with the library LIBSVM?
LIBSVM doesn't have laplace kernel orginally. Is there anyway to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You will need to read the documentation of LIBSVM, in particular the README file has a section on Precomputed Kernels where it explains how to do it. You can do it from Matlab, in that case you will need to also read the examples on the usage of precomputed kernels, again in the MATLAB README file of LIBSVM.

That being said, and I know you're not asking for advice, but this probably isn't the first thing to try, the first thing to try is to use the RBF kernel which is almost identical to the Laplacian kernel except in some minor technical details.